# Is a two-stage dynamic game with complete but imperfect information really just a static game?

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

Let's say that we have this dynamic game with complete  but imperfect information represented in extensive form:
[the dynamic game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Xmd.png)

Isn't this dynamic game just identical to a regular static game? I do know that normal form games and extensive form games are convertible, but in this case, why would you even call it a dynamic game with complete  but imperfect information? Isn't it just confusing to call such a game dynamic if it is a static game?

Answer (score 0):

You make a good point. Let me try to spell it out for you. "Dynamic" vs. "static" are interpretive labels, whereas "complete" and "imperfect" information are formal notions.

You can *interpret* this game with complete and imperfect information as a dynamic game, where 1 chooses his strategy and afterward (having no knowledge of 1's move) 2 chooses hers. Or you can *interpret* it as a static game where they make simultaneous choices. From the point of view of game theory, because the formal description is the same, there is very little practical difference.